# Me ayudan a encontrar el error en este css

Tags: css

Estoy tratando de ubicar un *icon*, pero por algún motivo el código me muestra 2 errores y no me aparece la linea del error. Ayuda por favor, uso Visual Estudio y tengo que presentar esto esta tarde, estaría muy agradecido si me ayudaran.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Yanone+Kaffeesatz&display=swap');

    {
        box-sizing:border-box
    }
    img{
        display: block;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    body{
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }

    h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
        font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
        letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    }
    .header{
        height: 60px;
    }
    .header .contenedor {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .logo, .icon-menu {
        margin: 5px;
    }
    .icon-menu {
        display:block;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        font: size 30px;;
        background: FBA919  ;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 45px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .nav {
        position: absolute;
        top:60px;
        left:0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;;
    }
```

Comment: Podrias subir un ejemplo de como quieres que quede y el html para hacer pruebas mas facil.

Comment: Puedes agregar una captura de pantalla de los dos errores que te aparecen.

Comment: Son las dos primeras lineas de codigo, no puedes importar un archivo que no sea `css`, en fonts.google indica que es lo que debes de hacer para incluir las fonts.

Comment: @Shassain eso no es cierto, puedes importar fuentes así

Comment: @JheymanMejia preferiblemente se deben incluir los mensajes de error como texto. Sólo si va a mostrar la interfaz en su estado deseado y el actual, tiene sentido poner imágenes.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia esta linea:

`font: size 30px`

por

`font-size: 30px;`

> En este caso esta mal la propiedad. Es `font-size`

Y esta otra

`margin: 0;;`

por

`margin: 0;`

> En esta caso te sobra un `;`

Answer (score -1):

Aquí te dejo la corrección de tu código

```
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}

.header {
    height: 60px;
}

.header .contenedor {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo,
.icon-menu {
    margin: 5px;
}

.icon-menu {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color: #FBA919;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 45px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

.menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Puedes indicar por qué, qué puede hacer para corregirlo?